# CSS. Цвет картинки как шрифт. Инверсия

Tags: html, css, img

Проблема в следующем:
Есть текст-ссылка, цвет шрифта - синий, цвет фона - белый.

```
<a href="#">ссылка</a>
```

Средствами CSS при наведении цвета меняются.

```
a {color:blue; background:white;}
a:hover {color:white; background:blue;}
```

Перед текстом ссылки будет стоять иконка (ч/б или спрозрачностью).

```
<a href="#"><img src="ico.png"/>ссылка</a>
```

либо

```
<a href="#"><img src="ico.jpg"/>ссылка</a>
```

Существует возможность сделать так что бы картинка работала как маска?
То есть в конкретном примере нужно что бы при наведении курсора иконка меняла цвет с синего на белый.

Answer (score 6):

Придумал интересный костыль (при условии, что картинка однотонная по прозрачному):

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: .25em;
  color: #157EFB;
  background-color: white;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #157EFB;
}

a:hover img {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  filter: drop-shadow(128px 0 0 white);
}
```

```html
<a><span><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/K8JyZ.png" height=128 width=128></span> + text</a>
```

Comment: это уже поинтереснее вариант)

Comment: Ого, круто придумано!

Comment: наверное самым гибким способом будет использование hue-rotate для смены цвета и brightness для создания белого цвета...

Comment: @Павел, пробуй. Вроде этот вариант хороший, не?

Comment: Самое то что надо) Запилил тест https://jsfiddle.net/Ciberpol/so2zbmye/

Спасибо за правильное направление)

Comment: @Павел, для каждого цвета своё решение... Ладно, публикуй ответом и принимай через 2 дня, раз нравится...

Comment: не, там можно еще пару классов дописать на цвет по умолчанию. По крайней мере саму картинку переделывать не нужно. Все можно собрать на лету заменой классов в теле html или цветового угла в css

еще бы придумать как задавать цвет картинки в HEX, а не подбирать градусами)))

Answer (score 3):

Да, есть filter invert. Можно было бы залить span белым и инвертировать его, но я сделал несколько по-другому:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  padding: .25em;
}

span:hover {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

span:hover img {
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<span><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5XdlR.png" height=128 width=128> + text</span>
```

Comment: хм... может попробовать дивы и background-blend-mode...

Comment: @Павел, я уже поинтереснее костыль придумал. Опубликовал отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Как паршивый (только для самых свежих браузеров), но вариант:

```
a:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(1000%);
  webkit: grayscale(100%) brightness(1000%);
}
```

Пример:

```css
.bg {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 8px 4px;
  background: #aaa;
}

.bg:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(1000%);
  webkit: grayscale(100%) brightness(1000%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://s.imgur.com/images/imgur-logo.svg">
</div>
```

[Все фильтры](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: 1. webkit => filter. 2. Поменяй местами префиксную и нормальную запись. 3. Что-то странное решение с 1000%...

Comment: Дык это совсем не то. Такой способ просто сделает картинку чернобелой.

Comment: Вроде вполне нормальная поддержка, ну кроме Edge12-.

Comment: @Qwertiy, чтобы сделать картинку из синей белой? Вроде бы нет другого способа.

Comment: Ой.. А вот это я не подумал...

Comment: видимо SVG придется использовать(

Comment: @Павел, с `brightness(…)` же долго осветлить картинку, нет?

Comment: а прозрачность с brightness (если использую png) не пропадет? не станет вся картинка белым квадратом?

Comment: @Павел, не, не станет, проверил перед тем, как написать.

Comment: в принципе допустимый способ, для конкретного примера. Но на лету в CSS под разные цвета уже не заточить будет. Скажем если использовать зеленый фон и желтый шрифт, то с картинкой уже придется колдовать.

Comment: А я придумал ещё один фильтрокостыль для однотонных изображений...